# Is it possible to load/save the whole structure of plist in setting bundle using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone

I know it can use NSDictionary to load and save whole plist file on iphone document directory with its structure.

But is it possible to load/save the whole structure of plist in setting bundle using NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the following works for saving arrays in NSUserDefaults so it should work fine for a NSDictionary

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictionary forKey:@"Dictionary"];
```

Hope that helps